# What does NULL means in Extra coulmn of MySql Explain

Tags: mysql

I have a quite big query with multiple joins and one sub-query. Due to huge amount of data query is taking a lots of time. When i tried to EXPLAIN the query, i found that query is not using indexes properly although they are present in the corresponding tables.
For one of my table, Explain's Extra column is showing NULL. Can someone help me out to understand the meaning of it.

Here are the details of EXPLAIN.

```
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+  
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys                       | key                     | key_len | ref                            | rows   | Extra                    |  
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+  
|  1 | PRIMARY     | results        | index | PRIMARY                             | value                   | 202     | NULL                           |    253 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |  
|  1 | PRIMARY     | report         | ref   | Index_Result,Index_TimeRecord       | Index_Result            | 8       | SCHEMA.results.id              |   6056 | NULL                     |  
|  1 | PRIMARY     | user           | ref   | Index_user                          | Index_user              | 192     | func                           |      1 | Using index              |  
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>     | ref   | <auto_key0>                         | <auto_key0>             | 8       | SCHEMA.report.time_record.id   |     10 | Using where              |  
|  2 | DERIVED     | time_record    | ref   | index_monthyear                     | index_monthyear         | 4       | const                          | 139200 | Using where              |  
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+  
5 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `currentmonth`.`year` AS `c0`, `currentmonth`.`monthdisplay` AS `c1`, `currentmonth`.`month` AS `c2`, `currentmonth`.`day` AS `c3`, 
`user`.`userid` AS `c4`, `user`.`name` AS `c5`, `results`.`id` AS `c6`, `results`.`name` AS `c7` 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM time_record WHERE 
`month`=DATE_FORMAT(@curr_date:=CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'GMT',olsentimezone),'%m') - 0 AND 
`year`=DATE_FORMAT(@curr_date,'%Y'))
 AS `currentmonth`, `report` AS `report`, `user` AS `user`, 
`results` AS `results` WHERE `report`.`timeid` = `currentmonth`.`id` 
AND `report`.`userid` = `user`.`userid` AND 
`report`.`resultid` = `results`.`id` 
GROUP BY 
`currentmonth`.`year`, `currentmonth`.`monthdisplay`, 
`currentmonth`.`month`, `currentmonth`.`day`, `user`.`userid`, `user`.`name`, `results`.`id`, 
`results`.`name` 
ORDER BY 
ISNULL(`currentmonth`.`year`) ASC, `currentmonth`.`year` ASC, ISNULL(`currentmonth`.`month`) ASC, 
`currentmonth`.`month` ASC, ISNULL(`currentmonth`.`day`) ASC, `currentmonth`.`day` ASC, ISNULL(`user`.`userid`) ASC, `user`.`userid` ASC, 
ISNULL(`results`.`id`) ASC, `results`.`id` ASC;
```

Comment: `NULL` in the output of `EXPLAIN` has the same meaning as everywhere else: the value is unknown or not available. Or, if you like it this way, there is no extra information for that join.

Comment: Please also post the query that generated this output. It helps understanding the execution plan and providing suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Hi @axiac, thanks for the response. i am using saiku which generates the query based on the fields selected for the report, means query is dynamic.  For above explain, i have added the query.

Comment: report table is my main table which contains around ~3 million records and explain does not gave me the details how it is being used.